# Booting problems after updating to 16.04

Tags: updates, 16.04

I recently updated to 16.04 using the software manager. Now on startup it flashes between different messages very fast. By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> I can get it to stop. When I do this, the screen is filled with the messages:

```
apcid.service
plymouth-start.service
plymouth-start. service
```

This is repeated and fills the screen.
By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> I can see another message which is:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda1: clean, 569953/9519104 files, 10826521/38047232 blocks
```

With <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> I can log in to a terminal session but have no idea what to do after that.